# Organize by Twitter unique identifier using python

Tags: python, twitter

I have a CSV file with each line containing information pertaining to a particular tweet (i.e. each line contains Lat, Long, User_ID, tweet and so on). I need to read the file and organize the tweets by the User_ID. I am trying to end up with a given User_ID attached to all of the tweets with that specific ID.

Here is what I want:

```
user_id: 'lat', 'long', 'tweet'
       : 'lat', 'long', 'tweet'
user_id2: 'lat', 'long', 'tweet'
        : 'lat', 'long', 'tweet'
        : 'lat', 'long', 'tweet'
```

and so on...

This is a snip of my code that reads in the CSV file and creates a list:

```
UID = []
myID = []
ID = []
f = None
with open(csv_in,'rU') as f:
    myreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in myreader:

        # Assign columns in csv to variables.
        latitude = row[0]
        longitude = row[1]
        user_id = row[2]
        user_name = row[3]
        date = row[4]
        time = row[5]
        tweet = row[6]
        flag = row[7]
        compound = row[8]
        Vote = row[9]

        # Read variables into separate lists.
        UID.append(user_id + ', ' + latitude + ', ' + longitude + ', ' + user_name + ', ' + date + ', ' + time + ', ' + tweet + ', ' + flag + ', ' + compound)
        myID = ', '.join(UID)
        ID = myID.split(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `pandas` for this. It will allow you not only to list your tweets by `user_id`, as in your question, but also to do many other manipulations quite easily.

As an example, take a look at [this python notebook from NLTK](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/test/twitter.ipynb). At the end of it, you see an operation very closed to yours, reading a `csv` file containing tweets,

> ```
> In [25]:
>
> import pandas as pd
> ​
> tweets = pd.read_csv('tweets.20150430-223406.tweet.csv', index_col=2, header=0, encoding="utf8")
> ```

You can also find a simple operation: looking for the tweets of a certain user,

> ```
> In [26]:
>
> tweets.loc[tweets['user.id'] == 557422508]['text']
> Out[26]:
> id
> 593891099548094465    VIDEO: Sturgeon on post-election deals http://...
> 593891101766918144    SNP leader faces audience questions http://t.c...
> Name: text, dtype: object
> ```

For listing the tweets by `user_id`, you would simply do something like the following (this is not in the original notebook),

```
In [9]:

tweets.set_index('user.id')[0:4]

Out[9]:
created_at  favorite_count  in_reply_to_status_id   in_reply_to_user_id retweet_count   retweeted   text    truncated
user.id                             
107794703   Thu Apr 30 21:34:06 +0000 2015  0   NaN NaN 0   False   RT @KirkKus: Indirect cost of the UK being in ...   False
557422508   Thu Apr 30 21:34:06 +0000 2015  0   NaN NaN 0   False   VIDEO: Sturgeon on post-election deals http://...   False
3006692193  Thu Apr 30 21:34:06 +0000 2015  0   NaN NaN 0   False   RT @LabourEoin: The economy was growing 3 time...   False
455154030   Thu Apr 30 21:34:06 +0000 2015  0   NaN NaN 0   False   RT @GregLauder: the UKIP east lothian candidat...   False
```

Hope it helps.